# Computer says rect.topleft() and rect.collidepoint() aren't recognized despite them being part of pygame module

Tags: python, pygame

import pygame, pygamecolors

pg = pygame
pgc = pygamecolors

class Button():
def **init**(self, x, y, image, scale):
width = image.get_width()
height = image.get_height()
self.image = pg.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), (int(height * scale))))
self.rect = self.image.get_rect
self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
self.clicked = False

```
def draw(self, surface):
    action = False
    # get mouse position
    pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()

    ## check mouseover and clicked conditions
    if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
        if pg.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
            self.clicked = True
            action = True

        if pg.mouse.get_pressed == 0:
            self.clicked = False

        # draw button screen
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect.x, self.rect.y)

        return action
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some calling parantheses missing in the line

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect
```

This should be:

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

The absence of the parantheses causes python to store the function (`pygame.Surface.get_rect`) instead of the image's rect in the `self.rect` attribute. This function does not have the attributes `topleft` and `collidepoint`, which a `pygame.Rect` does have. Trying to get these unexistent attributes causes python to crash.